# What can we do in following situation?

Tags: laravel, web, logic, weblogic

I have three tables `betsinfo`, `results` and `wallet`.

I have developed the app till the user bets and results are posted and the bets gets settled as win or lose in the `betsinfo` table.

But I am stuck as for logic on how can I settle the amount in the wallets table?

The winning bets should be calculated with `to_win_amt - stake = winning amount`.

I have all the bets placed in the system in `betsinfo` table and I am settling the bets by matching the `results` table.

Now I want to find out the creator of the `user` and match it with `wallet id` of the user and settle all their unsettled bets.

How can I achieve this? Any logic help, please?

#### Betsinfo Table

[image: Betsinfo]

#### Wallet Table

[image: Wallet]

#### Results

[image: Results]

Comment: please provide structure of tables

Comment: i have attached tables